# check output for success/error messages in PDO class

Tags: php, pdo

```
$pdo = new PDO(...); 
$stmt = $pdo -> prepare($query);
$stmt -> bindValue(1,$url); 
$stmt -> execute();
```

How I check if my query is executed with success?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Manual](http://php.net/manual/) is your friend

[`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.execute)

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

[`PDOStatement::errorCode()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.errorcode)
[`PDOStatement::errorInfo()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.errorinfo)

```
if (!$stmt->execute()) 
  throw new Exception('[' . $stmt->errorCode() . ']: ' . $stmt->errorInfo());
```